# discrete harmonic extension (an exercise of Grimmett's "probability on graphs")

Tags: probability, discrete-geometry, potential-theory

I'm struggling with exercise 1.3 in Grimmett's book "probability on graphs". Take $G = (V,E)$ a finite connected graph with given positive conductances $(w_e)_{e \in E}$, and let $(x_v)_{v \in V}$ be a family of numbers with total sum equal to 0. We add to the graph $G$ an extra vertex $\infty$, and each site of $V$ is joined to this new vertex $\infty$ by an edge $\langle v,\infty \rangle$ (the exercise does not make it very clear, but I understand that the conductances of these edges are of our choosing). The question is to show that there exists a current $i$ (i.e. a flow satisfying Kirchoff's laws) on the extended graph, such that the current crossing the edge $\langle v,\infty \rangle$ is $x_v$.

I attempted a few things, but so far unsuccessfully. In particular, the exercise is supposed to be the continuation of another exercise where currents are described in terms of the counting of spanning trees. Let me recall this here. For every edge $\langle a, b \rangle$, let us say that a spanning tree $T$ satisfies the property $\Pi(s,a,b,t)$ if the unique path in $T$ going from $s$ to $t$ crosses the edge $\langle a, b \rangle$ in the direction from $a$ to $b$. Let 
$$
N^*(T) = \prod_{e \in T} w_e,
$$
$$
N^*(s,a,b,t) = \sum_{T \text{ satisfies } \Pi(s,a,b,t)} N^*(T),
$$
and 
$$
N^* = \sum_T  N^*(T),
$$
where the last two sums are for spanning trees $T$. Then the unit current $i$ between $s$ and $t$ is such that
$$
i_{a,b} = \frac{1}{N^*} \big(N^*(s,a,b,t)  - N^*(s,b,a,t)  \big).
$$
This may be interesting for the problem I mentionned before, because we can decompose the set of spanning trees as follows. Either the spanning tree goes across only one edge of the type $\langle v,\infty \rangle$, in which case it does not contribute to the computation of the current across that edge ; else, two edges are crossed. In this case, we can decompose the part of the spanning tree within the original graph $G$ in two parts, forming a ``bush'' in Grimmett's terminology, i.e. a spanning set that has two connected components. I tried to use this decomposition to relate to currents in the original graph, but failed so far. Any help would be appreciated...

By the way, Grimmett's book is available for download on his web site, [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~grg/books/pgs.html).

Comment: Are conductances assumed to be positive real numbers?

Comment: yes, I'll edit the question to make it clear (sorry about that).

Comment: If there's a simple answer here, it's probably that the earlier answer produces a nontrivial solution to the homogeneous problem (Kirchoff's laws) with nonzero current in the target edge $<v,\infty>$.  By scaling you then get the specified current $x_v$ on that edge.  But I'll take a look at the book before speculating further.

Comment: do you know the energy minimization formulation ?  I think the hard part of the question is to show that there are flow with $x_{\nu}$ as stated.  There are, with the given condition.  One can be produced as the minimizer of $\sum_V (\sum_{w \sim v} i_{vw})^2$.  Then a second round of minimizing over the energy of flows satisfying the condition produces the flow you are looking for.

Comment: @hardmath: the problem is that the current is prescribed on every edge linked to the vertex $\infty$ simultaneously, while my impression is that your approach would give the correct current on one edge only.

Comment: @mike: I know about the energy minimization formulation, but I don't understand your approach. Let's agree that there are flows with $(x_v)$ as stated. Then why can one be produced as the minimizer of the energy you write ? What do you mean by "a second round of minimizing..." ? Shouldn't your energy include the resistance of the edges ?

Comment: @mike: I kind of see what you mean, but I don't see why it should work. First, shouldn't the energy to be minized rather be $\sum_{e \in E} r_{e} i_{e}^2$, where $r_{e}$ is the inverse of the conductance $w_e$? Second, I'm not sure if your procedure will give a flow if the values on the edges $\langle v, \infty \rangle$ are fixed. Third, I don't understand the "second round" of minimization. Do you mean that you minimize over the value of the flow across $\langle v, \infty \rangle$ ? Then the desired property will be broken.

Comment: yes, I  looked in a graph theory book to see how one produce a flow  in the source-trough formulation.  They had a longish argument starting from minimizing  sum of absolute values rather than squares. A flow has a value of 0 for that, by definition, as it has for this quadratic.  Then you move on to minimizing the energy, and it seemed that as long as you know that the class of flow with some prescribed values over which you are minimizing is non-empty, minmizing the energy, which has the 'r' in  it, works.

Comment: @mike: I don't really understand, can you tell me what is your reference ?

Comment: Diestel, Graph Theory

Comment: @mike: thanks for the indication. I didn't manage to find somthing useful in there though, can you be a bit more precise ?